# How to populate in Model from View in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am just trying to fill my Model with the View values and all the model values are still empty. And every method that I tried to use from Tutorials didn't work. I can set the Values from the Model but I can't fill things like Drehrichtung which is bound on a view value.

Here is my Model:

```
 namespace PlaudertischSoftware.Models
{
    public class PlauderViewModel
    {
        public string Bild { get; set; }
        public bool IstObst { get; set; }
        public int Richtig { get; set; }
        public int Falsch { get; set; }
        public int Drehrichtung { get; set; }
        public int BestritteneRunden { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using PlaudertischSoftware.Models;
using PlaudertischSoftware.Sensoren;
using System.Linq;

namespace PlaudertischSoftware.Controllers
{
    public class PlauderController : Controller

    public ActionResult SpielView()
        {
            PlauderViewModel model = new PlauderViewModel();
            int index = 0;

            model.Bild = GetBild(out index);
            //TODO: Falls neue Bilder hinzu kommen, muss das hier aktualisiert werden
            if (index > 0 && index < 15)
            {
                model.IstObst = true;
            }
            else
            {
                model.IstObst = false;
            }

            var varfrut = new KeyValuePair<string, bool>();



            if (varfrut.Value == true && model.Drehrichtung > 0)
            {
                model.Richtig = model.Richtig++;
                model.Falsch = model.Falsch;
            }
            else
            {
                if (varfrut.Value == false && model.Drehrichtung < 0)
                {
                    model.Richtig = model.Richtig++;
                    model.Falsch = model.Falsch;
                }
                else
                {
                    model.Falsch = model.Falsch++;
                    model.Richtig = model.Richtig;
                }



                if (model.Falsch + model.Richtig == 9)
                {
                    return View("AuswertungsView", model);
                }
            }

            return View(model);
        }
        private string GetBild(out int index)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            var list = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30" };
            index = random.Next(list.Count);



            string bild = "~/Bilder/" + list[index] + ".jpg";

            return bild;
        }
         [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult TimerStopped(/*string customModel, */PlauderViewModel model)
        {

            //PlauderViewModel model = null;
            int index;

            string schwuchtelMICROSCHROTT = Request["txtRunde"].ToString();

            model.Bild = Url.Content(GetBild(out index));

            ObstSpielDaten obstSpielDaten = null;
            try
            {
                using (DatenbankKontext dbKontext = new DatenbankKontext())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        obstSpielDaten = dbKontext.ObstSpielDaten.FirstOrDefault();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //TODO: hier fehler abfangen
                    }

                    //Auswerten
                    AntwortAuswerten(ref model);

                    //Angleichen und berechnen der übergeben View Daten in der Datenbank
                    if (obstSpielDaten == null)
                    {
                        obstSpielDaten = new ObstSpielDaten(DBHelper.GetNextObstSpielDatenID());
                        obstSpielDaten.FalschAnzahl = model.Falsch;
                        obstSpielDaten.RichtigAnzahl = model.Richtig;

                        try
                        {
                            dbKontext.ObstSpielDaten.Add(obstSpielDaten);
                            int anzahlAenderungen = dbKontext.SaveChanges();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            //TODO: hier fehler abfangen
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

            return Json(model);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my View:

```
@using DevExtreme.AspNet.Mvc;

@section Styles {
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/design.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("SpielView", "Plauder", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <h1 align="center" style="font-weight:bold">Ist hier Obst zu sehen?</h1>
    <div align="center" id="Bild_und_Counter">
        <img id="imgFruchtBild" style="position:center; border:ridge; border-color:#3f464c" src="@Url.Content(Model.Bild)" width="600" height="450" />
    </div>
    <div id="counter" align="center">
        <input type="button" name="CounterR" value="richtig:" style="font-size:x-large; font-weight:bold; width:85px; text-align:center; background-color:orange; border:thick; border-color:orange" />
        <input id="ipRichtig" type="number" name="ipRichtig" value="@Model.Richtig" style="font-size:x-large; font-weight:bold; width:35px; text-align:center; background-color:orange; border:thick; border-color:orange; margin-right:80px">
        <input type="button" name="CounterF" value="falsch:" style="font-size:x-large; font-weight:bold; width:85px; text-align:center; background-color:orangered; border:thick; border-color:orangered" />
        <input id="ipFalsch" type="number" name="ipFalsch" value="@Model.Falsch" style="font-size:x-large; font-weight:bold; width:35px; text-align:center; background-color:orangered; border:thick; border-color:orangered" />
    </div>
    <div class="lineargauge">
        @(Html.DevExtreme().LinearGauge()

     .ID("lineargauge")
     .Scale(s => s
     .StartValue(-20)
     .EndValue(20)
     .TickInterval(20)
     .Tick(t => t.Color("#536878"))
     .Label(l => l.CustomizeText(@<text>
     function(arg){
     if(arg.value > 0){
     return "Ja";
      }
     else if(arg.value < 0 ){
     return "Nein";
      }
     else{
     return "0";
      }
     }
     </text>)
    )
  )
     .RangeContainer(r => r
     .Offset(10)
     .Ranges(c =>
     {
      c.Add().StartValue(-20).EndValue(0).Color("orangered");
      c.Add().StartValue(0).EndValue(20).Color("orange");
     })
      )
     .ValueIndicator(v => v.Offset(20))
     .SubvalueIndicator(s => s.Offset(-15))
     .Export(e => e.Enabled(true))
     .Tooltip(x => x
     .Enabled(true)

)
    .Title(t => t
    .Font(f => f.Size(28))
)

     .Value(new JS("drehen"))
     .ValueIndicator(i => i
     .BaseValue(@Model.Drehrichtung)
     .Type(GaugeIndicatorType.TriangleMarker)
     .Color("#3f464c")
)
        )
    </div>
    <div class="form">
        @(Html.DevExtreme().Button()

     .ID("progress-button")
     .Text("Starten")
     .Width(120)
     .OnClick("button_onClick")
        )
    </div>
    <div class="progress-info">
        <br />
        <span>Runde: <input id="txtRunde" type="number" value="@Model.BestritteneRunden" style="width: 15px; border-width: 0px"/>von 10</span>
        <br />
        Übrige Zeit 00:00:<span id="timer">10</span>
    </div>

    <div id="progress-info">
        @(Html.DevExtreme().ProgressBar()

    .ID("progressBarStatus")
    .Min(0)
    .Max(100)
    .Width("100%")
    .Height(50)
    .StatusFormat(new JS("progressBar_statusFormat"))
    .OnComplete("progressBar_onComplete")
    .OnValueChanged("progressBar_valueChanged")
        )

        <div>
            @(Html.DevExtreme().Slider()

    .ID("handler-slider")
    .Min(-20)
    .Max(20)
    .Value(new JS("drehen"))
    .Width(1140)
    .Visible(false)
    .OnValueChanged(@<text>

     function(e){
     $("#lineargauge").dxLinearGauge("instance").value(e.value);
}
</text>)
            )
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dx-field-label">Anzahl der Umdrehungen</div>
    <div class="dx-field-value">
        @(Html.DevExtreme().NumberBox()

    .ID("slider-value")
    .InputAttr(false)
    .Value(new JS("drehen"))
    .Min(-20)
    .Max(20)
    .Width(200)
    .ShowSpinButtons(true)
    .OnValueChanged("numberBox_valueChanged")

        )
    </div>
```

Comment: I see that you have not set a value for Drehrichtung property in Controller (SpielView action). In order to use any property, first you have to set a value to it in Controller.

Comment: And how do I do this?

Comment: With the same way you set Bild, IsObst, Richtig and Falsch properties. You have set them all but not Drehrictung property.

Comment: But can I set the Drehrichtung value as same as the drehen value in my view?

Comment: I am not sure if I get your point right but if you want to update a model or pass any data to an Action of a Controller, you have to post these values from view by submitting a form. Please see this tutorial page for reference. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/controller-methods-views?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: The main problem is, that if I'm creating a json in the view, like with my function "GetModelJson()" and send it with ajax in "progressBar_onComplete" even as string, the parameter of my function "TimerStopped" in my controller is not filled. (tried parameters of type string and PlauderViewModel).

Answer (score 1):

You are not referencing **`model`** in your view. Below line of code will work at the beginning of your view:

```
@model PlaudertischSoftware.Models.PlauderViewModel
```

Put appropriate model in declaration.

Comment: But the problem remains still the same. The value "model.Drehrichtung" which is bound to "drehen" in my view won't still populate